# How To Delete Duplicates Based On File Age

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to delete duplicates files and only keep the original (oldest file). I need it to work with directories and be able to set the path i.e. E:media/, The directories will have files that arent duplicates (i need to keep those) and files with duplicates (sometimes more than 1 duplicate).

I have been able to put together a script that will do this based on hash but I cant seem to get it to work right if I set the path and it doesnt work with directories.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File | 
            Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, @{n="hash";e= {(Get-FileHash $_).Hash}} | 
                Sort-Object Hash,LastWriteTime

for ($i=1; $i -lt $files.count; $i++){ 
     Write-Host $i
     If ($files[$i].hash -eq $files[$i-1].hash){ 
              Remove-Item -Path $files[$i].fullname
     }
}
```

I changed

```
$files=Get-ChildItem E:/media -File
```

and

```
 Get-ChildItem E:/media -File
```

but doesn't work, and I cant figure out how to make it work in a directory, it only works inside said folder, I have 10000's of folders I need to sort out.

Im stumped and will appreciate any pointers in the right direction, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to simplify *Mathias R. Jessen's* answer slightly, you can do everything in one line:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Media -Recurse -File | # Recursively find files
    Group-Object -Property {(Get-FileHash $_.FullName).Hash} | # Group by file hash
        Where-Object Count -gt 1 | # Groups with more than one item contain duplicates
            ForEach-Object { $_.Group } | # 'Expand' groups with duplicates
                Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | # Oldest item will be first
                    Select-Object -Skip 1 | # Skip first (oldest) item
                        Remove-Item -Force # Remove duplicate files
```

The above will remove duplicates from everywhere in the directory tree.  If you only want to remove duplicates in the same directory, this slightly amended code (which groups by hash *and* containing directory) will do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Media" -File -Recurse |
    Group-Object -Property DirectoryName, {(Get-FileHash $_.FullName).Hash} |
        Where-Object Count -gt 1 |
            ForEach-Object { $_.Group |
                Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
                    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
                        Remove-Item -Force
        }
```

Comment: we should not. Cause the explanation matters. That one liner can be done by himself but he didn't to make the user understand

Comment: Ranadip Dutta, fair enough.

Comment: @boxdog this works only if duplicates are in a single folder but if duplicates are in more than 1 folder it will delete all instances of that file leaving no unique file behind. (which Is fine for me but thought I'll point it out as a FYI for someone else), I have another question. All my files only need to be checked against other files in the same folder for duplicates and ignore files in the other folders.So I have 1000's of folders but want to check only each folder contents individually for duplicates not the entire directory files against each other, hoping you can help with that

Comment: Juan Lopez, I've added an updated snippet that should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by finding all duplicate pairs and ignore the rest. Then go through each pair/group of duplicates and sort those:

```
# Find all groups of duplicate files
$DuplicateGroups = Get-ChildItem E:\media -Recurse -File |Group {
  (Get-FileHash $_.FullName).Hash
} |Where-Object Count -gt 1

# Go through each group
foreach($Duplicates in $DuplicateGroups){
  # Remove all files except for the oldest one
  $Duplicates.Group |Sort-Object LastWriteTime |Select -Skip 1 |Remove-Item
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean :)

Comment: Thanks, another thing, will it be possible to treat each folder as it own contained folder to check duplicates against? I don't need to check all files in all the directories against each other just the files inside the same directory. for instance folder 1 files will only need to be checked against other files in folder 1, and folder 2 only against other files in folder 2 etc etc.